# What to chose as light infile nosql data storage for .NET application?

Tags: .net, mongodb, cassandra, couchdb, nosql

I found fine .NET bindings on **MongoDB**; **CouchDB**; **Cassandra cluster**; **RavenDB**; **db4o**.

I'm new with NoSQL. I need to store Industrial data, not much text but lot of different floating point value archives. data structure is not dynamic. And it's better when I don't need to install any services for it to work or it must be automatic or pretty easy.

*Thank you*

Comment: any specific reason why you want to go for noSQL instead of SQL Compact edition or other SQL like embedded databases?

Comment: So there is no specific reason I just want to touch nosql. Maybe that could be used fine as light data storage solution for future projects and for current project too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Light, in-file (no services) NoSQL?

Sounds like you want [Berkeley DB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_DB). It looks like the [Berkeley DB download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/berkeleydb/downloads/index.html) includes C# and .Net support.

Comment: But It's not nosql... I will take a look but afaik they allow to pay or opensource instead of sqlite.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good comparison here: http://weblogs.asp.net/britchie/archive/2010/08/17/document-databases-compared-mongodb-couchdb-and-ravendb.aspx

IMO, MongoDB is the best for performance, and CouchDB is a very close 2nd. Ayende's RavenDB is good if your looking a solution that is a good fit with .NET -- especially when it comes to querying the stored documents.

There are several good .NET API's for both Couch and Mongo, and you can even try out CouchDB free at Cloudant.com if you don't want the hassle of setting it up in your own environment. I don't have any experience with Cassandra.